# How to pause a Google Cloud Composer Environment?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

We had spinned a google cloud composer environment, but need to use it only for testing purpose. Is there a way to pause the environment and only use it when needed?
I am unable to find a way to do it.

Please suggest if any solutions possible to pause or diable it, rather than deleting it.
Thanks!

I tried to find a way to disable/pause the environment but could not find any.

Comment: In short, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that but if you are using `Cloud Composer` 2, it uses a `GKE` with `autopilot` mode.

The `autopilot` mode is optimized if there is no DAGs executions in the cluster.

If it's used for testing purpose, I recommend you using the `small` environment size and a cheap and small configuration regarding worker and webserver : cpu, memory and storage..., example :

```bash
gcloud composer environments create example-environment \
    --location us-central1 \
    --image-version composer-2.0.31-airflow-2.2.5 \
    --environment-size small \
    --scheduler-count 1 \
    --scheduler-cpu 0.5 \
    --scheduler-memory 2.5 \
    --scheduler-storage 2 \
    --web-server-cpu 1 \
    --web-server-memory 2.5 \
    --web-server-storage 2 \
    --worker-cpu 1 \
    --worker-memory 2 \
    --worker-storage 2 \
    --min-workers 1 \
    --max-workers 2
```

Check the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/create-environments#scale-and-performance) for the best sizing in your case.